# Managing more directly connected project on git

Tags: git, github

First let me apologize if I making duplicate question since there are very similar question but none of them address my concerns.

I have 3 projects which are "coupled", meaning that changes on one will effect the other one. Each one of them is hosted github as separate git project. Projects are:

- server (... foo/server.git)
- cli client (... foo/cli-client.git)
- web client (... foo/web-client.git)

I have need for features branching, release branching, hotfix branching and in general releasing the software.

Obviously changes on web/cli client are coupled with changes on server and when I need to branch I need to create branch on each of those projects (branches often finish on origin so whole team can collaborate). After I need to merge back to master and so forth...

I would like to avoid this and have mechanism which would allow me to branch, version at the same time. Obvious answer to this is creating parent project which would have each projects as a sub folder and in the end keeping parent project on one git repo.

My question is what would be the downside to this? Approach seems little naive and I have to wonder is there better way to achieve this? I was looking into `git submodules` but it seems that they provide *downstream* and do not allow *upstream* which would allow me to branch and merge across all projects. (maybe I am wrong about this).

Thank you

Comment: One basic question : Do you always plan to make a branch of, say, cli client when there were changes in server and web client ? What I mean is, by default, each project should be handled seperately and then a mapping can be generated. For example : cli client version 2.4 is compatible with server version 1.7 and above. web client version 2 is compatible with server version 1 and above. Using such structure, you will be free to modify each client without creating un-necessary branches. Maybe I am totally off the track, but give it a thought.

Comment: @AYK Changes to CLI client will not always mean that there were server changes. And branch would span across the server, cli client and web client but changes would only be to cli part of the code. To be honest I do not know if this is such an overhead compare ted to maintaining version mapping, branch mapping accross 3 projects?

Answer (score 1):

There are some [issues with submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules#Issues-with-Submodules). Also, this is not what submodules feature in git has been created for and I would advise against using it in Your case.

You have 3 PROJECTS that are loosely related to each other, not one project in three repositories. Client application is using the Server and Web application is using the Server. Sometimes, but not always, the branch name on one project has the same name as in the other project, but from git's point of view, it's pure coincidence.

I've seen numerous development teams with a similar work environment and they have all used separate repositories and separate branches within them. Usually the work on the given topic was finished in one project days or weeks before it was even started in the other (or didn't require changing the other project at all).

If, however, You feel You need to automate this process, You could write a simple shell scripts "create-branch-on-all-projects.sh" and "merge-branch-on-all-projects.sh".

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I do agree that scripts are one way to go but do not see "bad side" of joining them as one project. Way things stand at the moment I will not lose anything if I join them under "one roof". Writing bash scripts will give me same end results, and it feel reduntant going that route if I am not getting anything for it. Only down side I see is that all developers will have access to all 3 projects but that is not a problem in our case.

Comment: 1. If You are not extreamly careful with submodules, You or one of Your collegues might loose data.  2. Submodules also adds overhead (more work needs to be done to release and pull). Follow the link in the answer to a good book on what it really does, but most importantly, don't let me get in Your head - it's Your project and You should do whatever You feel is best.

Comment: Best solution at the moment for me is to combine them as one project, on one repo. I will not use submodules, agree with you on that one.